# UIcollection view not getting call datasources

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

Hello Im creating a `UICollectionView` from xib. And this is my `.h` class

```
@interface ArtistViewController : <UIViewController<UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate>

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionview;
```

in my `.m` `ViewDidloadmethod` I did this

```
[collectionview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

My data sources and delegates are like this

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [dataArray count];
}



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView {
return 1;
}





 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"CollectionViewCell";

CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


//artist = [arrayClass.mutArrayArtists objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
if([[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"thumbImage"]!=nil){


    recipeImageView.image=[[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"thumbImage"];
}
else
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"thumbUrl"]];
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if(image!=nil){
                NSMutableDictionary *objectDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
                [objectDict setObject:image forKey:@"thumbImage"];
                [dataArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:objectDict];
            }

            recipeImageView.image= image;

        });
    });
}



UILabel *lblArtistname=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
lblArtistname.text=[[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];

lblArtistname.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
[lblArtistname setNumberOfLines:0];

CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(300,800);
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [[lblArtistname text] sizeWithFont:lblArtistname.font
                                            constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
                                                lineBreakMode:[lblArtistname lineBreakMode]];
CGRect newframe=lblArtistname.frame;
newframe.size.height=expectedLabelSize.height;
newframe.size.width=300;
[lblArtistname setFrame:newframe];


//UILabel *lblSongCount=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
// lblSongCount.text=artist.numberofSongs;
return cell;
}
```

But this not getting call for any datasource method. Why is that. How can I solve this. Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In  .m ViewDidloadmethod add this

```
[self.collectionview setDelegate:self];
[self.collectionview setDataSource:self];
```

And correct the typo in first line as:

```
@interface ArtistViewController :    UIViewController<UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your storyboard (or view controller if you prefer) set the dataSource and delegate outlets of the UICollectionView to your view controller.  It also looks like you have a type in your @interface declaration.

```
@interface ArtistViewController : <UIViewController<UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate>
```

should be

```
@interface ArtistViewController : UIViewController<UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate>
```